# jQuery Datatables Toggle Button Populate Cell on Change

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am trying to create an online attendance register for a local club that records members/non-members attendance, how much they have to pay and if they have paid then store in database for future retrieval.

[image]

At the moment I am displaying the Subs using html/php

```
<td class="subs"><?php  

    if ($row['memb_stat'] == 'Member') {
        $subs = 3.50;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
        echo money_format('%.2n', $subs);

    }else{
        $subs = 5.00;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
        echo money_format('%.2n', $subs);
    }

?>
```

Which is just a temporary solution and obviously doesn't take into account the value of the first column.

What I would really like to happen is that when the toggle button status changes the appropriate Subs column cell populated with the correct price for their membership status.

I realise that this may be best done using JavaScript and perhaps ajax, but I can't seem to get even a basic cell population with a fixed value to work. This is the kind of thing I have been trying.

```
$(document).on('change', '.toggleBtn', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    $(this).bootstrapToggle('disable');

    var btn_button = $(this);
    var status = $(this).prop('checked');
    btn_button.html(' <i class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ');
    var tbl_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var tbl_status = $(this).data("status");
    if(tbl_status == 0) status = 1;
    else status = 0;

    //var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
        //$(this).attr('value', valor);

    //table.cell( $(this).closest('tr'), 7 ).data('3.50')
    table.cell( $(this).closest('tr'), 7 ).data("status");
    //setTimeout( function () {
        //table.draw();
    //}, 1000 );

    $.post('save_details.php', { form_name: "user_status", tbl_id: tbl_id, status: status }, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        if(status == "checked"){
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Record status changed successfully.");
            $('#warningModal').modal('show');
            setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            $('.warning-modal-message').html("Data deletion failed.");
        }
    });
});
```

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your PHP code for save_details.php?

Comment: Hello harry, yes I could but not sure how to do it without hitting the Answer Your Question button, which appears to close the question. Unless I'm completely wrong :)

Comment: You can always edit your post and add it there

Answer (score 0):

Probably no the most elegant solution, but it's working for now.

```
$(document).on('change', '.toggleBtn', function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();

$(this).bootstrapToggle('disable');

var subs = 3.50;

var btn_button = $(this);
var status = $(this).prop('checked');
btn_button.html(' <i class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ');
var tbl_id = $(this).attr("id");

var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
var membstat = currow.find('td:eq(5)').text();

if(membstat == 'Member') status = 1;
else status = 0;

if(membstat == 'Member'){
    currow.find('td:eq(6)').html(subs);
}else{
    currow.find('td:eq(6)').html('5.00');
};

$.post('save_details.php', { form_name: "user_status", tbl_id: tbl_id, status: status }, function(data,status){
    if(status == "checked"){
        $('.warning-modal-message').html("Record status changed successfully.");
        $('#warningModal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
    }
    else{
        $('.warning-modal-message').html("Data deletion failed.");
    }
});
});
```